# Firebase share event : can't see item id and content type in console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to use Firebase analytics in my Android app.

In the documentation, it is recommended to use events defined in the SDK as the integrate better in the Firebase console. Each type of event has some associated attributes, defined (in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#SELECT_CONTENT) and [support](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317498?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484)).

I have tried to use 2 types of events so far SELECT_CONTENT and SHARE. Here is my code :

```
//Reporting a content
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "Day" + Integer.toString(position));
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "daily_page");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

//Reporting a share
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, socialNetwork.getName() + "_" + themeAnalytics);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "daily_image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SHARE, bundle);
```

In the analytics console, I can see a nice "Content" chart when the event type selected is "select_content". However, when the event type selected is "share", this chart is not visible.

The number of events differ widely. There are a few thousands "content_type" events but only a dozens of "share" events. So I was wondering whether this could be a explanation. 
The only difference between the values I send is that the ITEM_ID of the share event contains an underscore, but I doubt that it causes the problem.

Has anyone experienced this situation ?

Comment: Do you log both events at the same time?

Comment: Hey. No, as they are different events. But the can potentially be close in time (less than a second), as they are fired by user actions.

Comment: Do you have any other Firebase or Google SDKs with your app? Also, are your events marked as conversion on the developer console?

Comment: Thanks for asking the first question, as it appears an unused dependency was still present "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.0".
The events (SELECT_CONTENT and SHARE) are not marked as conversion.